# Next Image not preserving aspect ratio set in contentful

Tags: css, image, next.js, tailwind-css

I have this extra wide image that im using as a banner. It has a defined height and width of 2560x670 but next js is rendering the image as 1789 × 438 px. How do i keep the aspect ratio at 2560x670? and still maintain object-fit: cover? I essentially want the left and right of the image to crop off the header when changing viewport width, and keeping the aspect ratio the same. See apple.com for an example.

Using next js v 12

`

```
    <div
      className={`relative flex justify-center px-componentPaddingMobile sm:px-componentPadding
              `}
    >
      {/*Background Images*/}
      <div className={`${smallHeroBackground ? "hidden tablet:flex" : "relative w-[2560px] h-[670px]"}`}>
        <Image
          src={`https:${heroMainBackground.fields.file.url}`}
          alt={heroMainBackground.fields.description}
          objectFit="cover"
          layout="fill"
          priority
        />
      </div>
    </div>
```

`

I've tried setting the container wrapping the image to the width and height of the actual photo, setting the w and h of the parent most component that renders the hero banner component, using sizes within the next image, and using state to create an aspect ratio within the image, and also trying to use the dynamic padding trick to the div holding the image to create the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

If this property is not working as you'd expected it to do, use `style="background-image: url('https:${heroMainBackground.fields.file.url}');"` in your view and add css to your div without any img:

```
div.myClassName {
  background-size: cover;
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Add a title attribute to your div (to replace alt={heroMainBackground.fields.description}) and an aria-label for accessibility